# How to send the image to API from modal window in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm using Fengyuan Chen Image Cropper in Django.
[Here you can see more about it](http://mafestival.be/blicsm/plugins/cropper-master/docs/)

After cropping the Image, I want to send the image to API and get the response in JSON.

This is how my views.py file looks like..

```
import json
import urllib.request
from .models import Photo
from .forms import PhotoForm

def photo_list(request):
    photos = Photo.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PhotoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.save():
                data = get_json("http://127.0.0.1:5000/")
            return render(request, 'album/photo_list.html', {'form': form, 'photos': photos, 'data': data})
    else:
        form = PhotoForm()
    return render(request, 'album/photo_list.html', {'form': form, 'photos': photos})

def get_json(url):
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    raw_json = html.read().decode('utf-8')
    forex_json = json.loads(raw_json)
    return forex_json
```

And here is how my photo_list.html form code looks like..

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formUpload" name="file">

    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
</form>
```

Where "file" is the name of the key.

I'm facing an issue where sending file using this form.

ERROR ::
 raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'file'

May be it's because it can't perform two tasks simultaneously. I'm new to Django. Any help will be really appreciable. Thanks